# Controller Extension with a form in SilverStripe 3 doesn't process on custom controllers

Tags: silverstripe

OK so this might seem a bit convoluted so I'll do my best:

1. I have a custom controller with a custom route that displays data
   objects as a page. TourController extends Page_Controller. For this
   example, say the rout to this page is
   /tours/south-america/patagonia/tour-name/. This works fine.
2. I have other normal pages throughout of the site that were added via the
   CMS
3. I have a new DataExtension that simply adds a form to all
   Page_Controller objects. Code below.

   ```
   class CurrencyPageExtension extends DataExtension {
   private static $allowed_actions = array(
       'CurrencyForm',
       'setCurrency'
   );

   public function CurrencyForm() {

       $currencies = [
           'NZD',
           'AUD',
           'USD',
           'GBP',
           'EUR'
       ];

       $currentCurrency = 'NZ';

       $currencyField = DropdownField::create('Currency', ' ', $currencies, $currentCurrency);
       $currencyField->addExtraClass('form-control');
       $currencyField->setAttribute('onchange', 'this.form.submit()');

       $fields = FieldList::create(
           $currencyField
       );

       $actions = FieldList::create(
           FormAction::create('setCurrency', 'Save')
       );

       $form = new Form(
           $this->owner,
           'CurrencyForm',
           $fields,
           $actions
       );

       return $form;

   }

   public function setCurrency($data, $form) {
       // Set currency stuff
       $this->owner->redirectBack();
   }

   }
   ```

In all pages, including the custom controller, the form is rendered just fine. It's when I submit that I get the issue. On the normal pages everything works great and the setCurrency action triggers. E.G. form is submitted to /home/CurrencyForm. On the custom controller however, the form is submitted to /TourController/CurrencyForm with a 404 error.

I have searched and found a couple of [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36232001/using-a-form-in-a-custom-controller) around creating a Link() method on the custom controller, and I successfully did that. However the 404 issue persists.

Any idea how I can do this. I'm half thinking it's just easier to put the action directly on Page_Controller, but I would rather keep all this code encapsulated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the formAction to always use /home/myform, e.g. `$form->setAction('/home/myForm');`

That's before returning the form. It should then always use that URL, regardless of what page you're on.

Comment: Great idea! The method is action setFormAction so thanks! $form->setFormAction('/home/CurrencyForm');